# After assigning value to html input from C# code behind, changes to text not reflected when submitted

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, input

I have a form, all input type="text" with runat="server" so the code behind can see it, that allows the user to input data, then later to edit the same data if selected from a list.  After populating the form for edit (which works fine) the user can change whatever fields they please and click submit.  The code works as it should but I realized nothing was being updated.

Upon debugging through the code I found that even though I had typed new text into the fields it was still sending the original text that was populated into the fields upon selection of the record to edit.

Also, when looking at the fields through javascript they reflect the current text in the fields as they should, but in the code behind they show what was originally assigned.

Code:

Loading the fields from data call:

```
protected void LoadForm(int detailId)
{
    List<Event> e = ado.GetEventDetails(detailId);
    txtEventName.Value = e[0].eventName;
    txtSponsOrg.Value = e[0].sponsOrg;
    txtSponsOrgContactName.Value = e[0].sponsOrgContactName;
    txtVenueName.Value = e[0].venueName;
    txtStreetAddress.Value = e[0].venueAddress;
    txtCity.Value = e[0].venueCity;
    txtState.Value = e[0].venueState;
    txtZip.Value = e[0].venueZip;
}
```

The Click Event:

```
protected void SubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendCreateEvent();
}
```

The following is supposed to show current data in text box.  When debugging it shows the original text in the box loaded from the method above, regardless of whether I've typed new text into the field.

```
private void SendCreateEvent()
{
    //get user info
    SessionManager sm = new SessionManager();
    int userId = sm.UserApplicationID;
    string userName = sm.UserLoginName;
    string userFName = sm.UserFirstName;
    string userLName = sm.UserLastName;
    string userEmail = sm.UserEmailAddress;

    //assign form field variables
    string eventName = txtEventName.Value;
    string sponsOrg = txtSponsOrg.Value;
    string sponsOrgContact = txtSponsOrgContactName.Value;
    string venueName = txtVenueName.Value;
    string venueAddress = txtStreetAddress.Value;
    string venueCity = txtCity.Value;
    string venueState = txtState.Value;
    string venueZip = txtZip.Value;
    string detailId = Session["DetailId"].ToString();

    ado.CreateEvent(detailId, userId, userName, userFName, userLName, userEmail, 
                    eventName, sponsOrg, sponsOrgContact, venueName, venueAddress,
                    venueCity, venueState, venueZip)
}
```

*edit* Page Load method (requested):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtApprovedDate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
  txtEventDate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
  txtEventTimeStart.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
  txtEventTimeEnd.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
  int detailId = 0;
  string loadForm = Session["LoadForm"].ToString();
  if (Session["DetailId"].ToString() != "")
  {
    detailId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["DetailId"]);
  }
  if (loadForm == "true")
  {
    LoadForm(detailId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you replace input with asp:TextBox?

Comment: how does your Page_Load method look like?

Comment: muratgu, page_load added

Comment: I have the feeling that you are rebinding the data on the fields and not checking for `if(!IsPostback)` so by the time it gets to the `LoadForm` method the data is already overwritten by the data bind logic. Can you confirm that this is not the case?

Comment: Win.  I was going to check that possibility out if nothing came out here.  The form is much larger than I posted, but it's just more of the same.  It's roughly 30 fields and all inherited from a previous developer.

Comment: That's a distinct possibility.  I'll look into it icarus.

Comment: ***Look like Icarus has sovled the problem. Let Icarus write the answer. Basically, you need `if (!IsPostBack) {}` inside `Page_Load` event***

Comment: where do you set the value in `Session["LoadForm"]`? I see where you read it but not where you set it.

Comment: It was the !IsPostBack Icarus.   And because you asked, LoadForm is being set from the home page of the site which is where the list of records resides.  This list is what they select from to edit the record.

Comment: @todd.pund glad you found the issue. Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer** (taken from the comments):

You are probably rebinding the data on the text fields and not checking for `if(!IsPostback)` so by the time it gets to the `LoadForm` method the data is already overwritten by the data bind logic.